# Huge number of sstables after adding server to existing cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

we are running test cassandra cluster of 8 nodes
running in single DC using Simple snitch and DateTieredCompactionStrategy
Cassandra Version 2.1.3
after adding new node(9th) to the cluster we see that number of sstables on newly joined server roughly equals to sum of all sstables on all servers in the cluster. and that number is huge as tens of thousands of sstables on newly added server.

Q1:is that what we should expect to happen?

Furthermore newly added server seems isn't overloaded, basically there are no pending/scheduled  compactions but the number of sstables isn't decreasing.

Q2:what could be the reason of not reducing number of sstables?

Q3:what we need to do to reduce number of sstables per server?

Thanks for your help

Comment: what version of cassandra? how many sstables are there on other servers? how many pending compactions under "nodetool compactionstats"

Comment: we are running 2.1.3

Comment: Are you using Virtual Nodes with same num_token? When you do a `nodetool status`, how is data distributed (Own column)? When you do a `nodetool netstats`on the new node, has streaming ended?

Comment: we are running 2.1.3
at the time I added server there was something like 500 sstables on each node in cluster
nodetool compactionstats output on one of servers
pending tasks: 1
   compaction type   keyspace          table   completed        total    unit   progress
        Compaction       DATA   metrics_full   450138788   2373261571   bytes     18.97%

Comment: yes num_token setting is identical on all hosts and equals 256
from status command: Data distributed equally among all nodes
netstats shows: Mode: NORMAL; Not sending any streams.;
as far as I can tell streaming finished successfully at the time server was added

Comment: @ChrisLohfink - dtcs has max_sstable_age_days which limits the number of sstables eligible for compaction. most operators set it fairly low - marcus suggest setting it at gcgs, I used to set it at 1 day so that my sstables were roughly a day of data. Most operators dont realize that sstables above max_sstable_age_days will not be compacted during streaming operations, which causes the explosion described in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known (unexpected, but not unsurprising) behavior due to the design of DTCS. It will happen, every time, if max_sstable_age_days is below the ttl cutoff. It will also happen when you remove a node from the cluster.

I'm planning on discussing this at C* Summit 2015 if my talk is accepted, and I've proposed an alternative approach to DTCS in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9666

Comment: Thanks Jeff, that's good to know.  I also have a few CFs running on DTCS, but they have behaved thus far.

Comment: Thanks! Say hi at summit.