# Cassandra sstables accumulating

Tags: cassandra

I've been testing out Cassandra to store observations.
All "things" belong to one or more reporting groups:

```
CREATE TABLE observations (
    group_id int,
    actual_time timestamp, /* 1 second granularity */
    is_something int,   /* 0/1 bool */
    thing_id int,

    data1 text,     /* JSON encoded dict/hash */
    data2 text,     /* JSON encoded dict/hash */
    PRIMARY KEY (group_id, actual_time, thing_id)
)
WITH compaction={'class': 'DateTieredCompactionStrategy',
         'tombstone_threshold': '.01'}
AND gc_grace_seconds = 3600;

CREATE INDEX something_index ON observations (is_something);
```

All inserts are done with a TTL, and should expire 36 hours after
"actual_time".  Something that is beyond our control is that duplicate
observations are sent to us.  Some observations are sent in near real
time, others delayed by hours.

The "something_index" is an experiment to see if we can slice queries
on a boolean property without having to create separate tables, and
seems to work.

"data2" is not currently being written-- it is meant to be written by
a different process than writes "data1", but will be given the same
TTL (based on "actual_time").

Particulars:

Three nodes (EC2 m3.xlarge)
Datastax ami-ada2b6c4 (us-east-1) installed 8/26/2015 
Cassandra 2.2.0

Inserts from Python program using "cql" module
(had to enable "thrift" RPC)

Running "nodetool repair -pr" on each node every three hours (staggered).

Inserting between 1 and 4 million rows per hour.
I'm seeing large numbers of data files:

```
$ ls *Data* | wc -l
42150
$ ls | wc -l
337201
```

Queries don't return expired entries,
but files older than 36 hours are not going away!

Comment: Might also want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431217/huge-number-of-sstables-after-adding-server-to-existing-cluster/31347085#31347085

Answer (score 0):

The large number SSTables is probably caused by the frequent repairs you are running.  Repair would normally only be run once a day or once a week, so I'm not sure why you are running repair every three hours.  If you are worried about short term downtime missing writes, then you could set the hint window to three hours instead of running repair so frequently.

You might have a look at [CASSANDRA-9644](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9644).  This sounds like it is describing your situation.  Also [CASSANDRA-10253](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10253) might be of interest.

I'm not sure why your TTL isn't working to drop old SSTables.  Are you setting the TTL on a whole row insert, or individual column updates?  If you run sstable2json on a data file, I think you can see the TTL values.

Comment: I may have started frequent repairs when I had a cluster of smaller nodes (running closer to full) and repairs were failing when out of space.

Comment: TTL is set on whole row insert.

Comment: I dropped the table, and restarted without doing any repairs.  The sstables are no longer multiplying like bunnies.  But old files are not being removed (except on restart).  sstable2json shows nothing but deleted rows.

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure: I have a love/hate relationship with DTCS. I manage a cluster with hundreds of terabytes of data in DTCS, and one of the things it does absolutely horribly is streaming of any kind. For that reason, I've recommended replacing it ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9666 ).

That said, it should mostly just work. However, there are parameters that come into play, such as timestamp_resolution, that can throw things off if set improperly.

Have you checked the sstable timestamps to ensure they match timestamp_resolution (default: microseconds)?

Comment: An undeleted entry:  ["2015-09-05 18\\:40Z:1618637:xxx","yyy",1441485944379000,"e",3259,1441489203],a deleted entry:  ["2015-09-05 14\\:28Z:93571:xxx",1441463731,1441463731900000,"d"]

Comment: I would have suggested 'sstablemetadata', which would give you timestamps. It looks like your timestamps are in micros, though I'm not sure what tool you're using to check, so I'm not sure of the format, either.

Comment: prev output is from sstable2json.... sstablemetadata gives: `Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
Bloom Filter FP chance: 0.010000
Minimum timestamp: 1441463429477001
Maximum timestamp: 1441463841759000
SSTable max local deletion time: 1441474459
Compression ratio: -1.0
Estimated droppable tombstones: 0.9144014277869302
SSTable Level: 0
Repaired at: 0
ReplayPosition(segmentId=1441464038299, position=291)`